# Resolve ambiguity extension property of class

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, cocoapods, ambiguous

In my project I use two libraries:

- [SwifterSwift](https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift)
- [Material](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material)

Both libraries have extension to many classes of UIKit. When I try to compile project an error occurs:

[image]

I tried to look for a solution, but each advices not using two libraries that cause conflict. Is there any chance to solve such a problem? Maybe some of the priorities in the compiler or some casting in code?

Environment:

- Xcode 9.3
- Swift 3.3
- Material 2.14.0
- SwifterSwift 4.1.1

Comment: Don't post screen shots post your code (as text)

Comment: @the4kman Thanks for answer. Can you explain how such a declaration should look like in code? For instance I would like to set `shadowColor` to `gray`

Comment: I tried that, but the error still occurs `Type 'SwifterSwift' has no member 'shadowColor'`. SwifterSwift extends UIView so I try `SwifterSwift.UIView.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray`, but still no success.

Comment: 2021 Xcode 13, still unresolved

Answer (score 2):

I personally wouldn't use those for just setting up a button, and do:

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

If you want to use one of those libraries, you might have to pick one and remove the other. Or be picky/careful about what you import. They seems to have a lot of the same extensions.
But before you do that, check out this link: https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift/issues/176

Comment: Yes, but this is a simple example of this error. This problem occurs in every property extended in both libraries such as: `borderColor`, `backgroundColor` and many others. I wonder if there is any global solution to this problem.

Comment: @Przemex3000  I updated my answer with a little more info and a link to SwifterSwift reported issue with an answer

Comment: Instead of or in addition to a link, you should _say_ what the known issue / solution is. Links can go bad, and it's best to _explain_ to the questioner yourself. If the OP is experiencing a known issue, it might even be best to rewrite the whole answer...?